# Contact Me Form for One Page Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in the process of creating a Contact Me form on a one page layout. I have most of the code setup but cannot seem to resolve an error that appears. I will place all the code with the error below. Note: I haven't setup the mailer yet, I was going to do that once this code was properly setup :)

```
#routes
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
  devise_for :users
  root 'welcome#index'
end

#form
<%= form_for @contact do |x| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= x.label :name %><br />
    <%= x.text_field :name %>
    <%= x.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

#ContactsController
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
   @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
   if @contact.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your message has been sent!"
      redirect_to :action => :index
   else
      flash[:notice] = "Try Again!"
   end
  end

  private   
   def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name)
   end
end

#Index View
<%= render partial: 'contacts/form' %>
```

The error I mostly receive is `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. I have also tried placing the `@contact = Contact.new` within the Index Action of the welcome controller, but that throws up this issue: `Unable to autoload constant Contact, expected .../app/mailers/contact.rb to define it`

If you have any suggestions, thoughts or opinions, please let me know =) Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

PS: If any further code is needed or information, just ask. There is a contact model with the various columns.

**Update**

I now have the `@contact = Contact.new` within my Index Action of my Welcome Controller. Ultimately trying to solve the mailer issue I receive.

Comment: The form code belongs which view page?

Comment: The form code is in a partial under the contact view folder which then is to be shown on the index view.

Comment: Then having `@contact = Contact.new` in `index` action is correct. The other error is something related to the mailer I guess.

Comment: That makes sense; however, that mailer issue is throwing me for a loop. I have *no* idea what that entails. I haven't setup the mailer yet. I did not think I would have to yet?

Comment: Wait. Can you post the filename of the `Contact` model.

Comment: Contact.rb is the name. There is nothing within the model. `class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
end`

Comment: Did you said `Contact.rb` with capital C, then it should be `contact.rb`

Comment: Yes, I am rendering the form. I have that posted as the last portion of the code I originally mentioned. Form is on the _form.html.erb (within Contact folder). I then have a `render partial: 'contacts/form'` within the index view of the welcome folder.

Comment: Pavan: Sorry, it is contact.rb, there is no capital in the filename.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87293/discussion-between-joe-dayvie-and-pavan).

Comment: Try changing `resources :contact, only: [:new, :create]` to `resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]`

Comment: Nope, same issue. Reset server too.

Comment: Do you have any code in `.../app/mailers/contact.rb` ? If you do, try commenting it out since you are not going to configure the mailer yet.

Answer (score 1):

First your routes are wrong (and the BTW the resources :contact line should be at top of file), think of it as a waterfall from top to bottom.

If you go to /routes, you'll see you're only creating the :create route because of the "only: [:create]" statement in resources :contact part of routes file.

It may seem counter intuitive but you need :new route too as this renders the new view you have in your controller. essentially restful rails routes are paired :new  submits to :create and :edit submits to :update. So :create and :update don't have a view, they render :new or :edit view if there is an issue.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I thought there should be a :new there, but was unsure. I remember adding but still nothing. Now that I **know** it should be, thank you, I have added but still the same mailer issue is there. Updated code too.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer to your question but it's easier to post code in this box than in the comments box. I saw a few things that need to be adress

```
  def create
    @contact = Contact.create(contact_params) #change to: @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      flash.notice = "Your message has been sent!" #change to: flash[:notice] = "Your message has been sent!"
      redirect_to :action => :index
    else
      flash.notice = "Try Again!" #change to: flash[:notice] = "Try Again!"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you =) May not be the answer but always good to receive input. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your input but I found my error. There was an issue with the name of the mailer which caused the issue. I had contact.rb when it needed to be contact_mailer.rb.

Thank you all for the other advice!